# Cannot insert value into mysql database with php script

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">  
 <label> Enter Email:</label><input type="text" name="email"/>
</form>
```

Here is the php:

```
<? 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password" ) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("data") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$email')");
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: besides using root to connect to your database, and using the deprecated `mysql_*` syntax that is terribly insecure? hmm ... what does your error say?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. If you're just getting started, a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) gives you more support than coding from scratch.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. It''s just not processing the form at all.

Comment: You're not getting errors because you're not checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - I'll bet it's a deprecated MySQL API. Also make sure that short tags are on. If not, change `<?` to `<?php`. You also don't have a submit button. If that's your full code, add one.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of things to comment on, but the specific cause of your error is case sensitivity. Your field name is `Email` but you are looking for `email` in the `$_POST` superglobal.

So

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

should be

```
$email=$_POST['Email'];
```

As for the other stuff, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) and using an [obsolete API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). I strongly recommend fixing this before pushing your code to production.

Comment: It seems like the OP changed the question/code. I smell deprecation. Plus, missing submit button if that's OP's full code.